# Using glm::mat4 with template class, comparing typedefs

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm writing a game engine using SDL2 & OpenGL and I am trying to use a template class to set some uniforms for my shaders.

Can someone assist me with my code to do the following:

1. compare the type of the parsed variable to check if it is a matrix
2. compare to a vec3 and then use value.x, value.y, value.z
3. compare to a float then simply store it.

```cpp
  template <class T>
  void SetUniform(char* uniform, T value)
  {
     GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaders[current_shader], uniform);
     if (loc != -1)
     {
        if (typeid(T) == typeid(glm::mat4))
           glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, value); // &mat4[0][0]
        else if (typeid(T) == typeid(int))
           glUniform1i(loc, value);
        else if (typeid(T) == typeid(glm::vec3))
           glUniform3f(loc, value.x, value.y, value.z); // vec3
        else
           glUniform1f(loc, value);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why not just write explicit specializations for every type of variable you are going to allow? Right now, you are trying to do something rather questionable -- if the typeid is unknown you assume that it is a floating-point scalar. You also query the uniform location by string name everytime you set it, which is silly. The uniform location never changes after linking, you should look for a way to pass around uniforms to your functions using the integer location rather than querying it by a name (which requires expensive string search operations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the type-id (which is an overkill here) you can do this with overloading elegantly with no runtime cost:

```
void SetUniform(const glm::mat4& mat, char *uniform)
{
    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaders[current_shader], uniform);
    if (loc != -1)
    {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]); // &mat4[0][0]
    }
}

void SetUniform(const glm::vec3& v, char *uniform)
{
    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaders[current_shader], uniform);
    if (loc != -1)
    {
        glUniform3f(loc, v.x, v.y, v.z);
    }
}

void SetUniform(float f, char *uniform)
{
    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(shaders[current_shader], uniform);
    if (loc != -1)
    {
        glUniform1f(loc, f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution, nice and clean, very similar to what I had working before I started with the template mess... it looks like I will be using this rather than getting the template to work, it's a shame.